# Rails Model Select Date Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I query for a certain date format. Right now, dates are stored as YYYY-MM-DD. How can I change that to MM-DD-YYYY?

This is using `sqllite` and how can I make this compatible when I push it to Heroku?

```
@users = User.select("id, first_name, last_name, middle_initial, datetime(dob, '%m/%d/%Y'), gender")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strftime](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime) method.

```
@users = User.select("id, first_name, last_name, middle_initial, strftime("%m-%d-%Y",dob), gender")
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Where do you enter the field like DOB?

Comment: I get the following error `SQLite3::SchemaChangedException: near "(": syntax error: SELECT id, first_name, last_name, middle_initial, dob.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), gender FROM...`

Comment: Can you just check the updated answer and let me know. I'm not familiar with sqlite.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to help you out and I said I've updated the answer.   Just check the select query. If it again goes wrong, wait for an expert in SQLite to answer your question.

Comment: The problem was the way the column was named. I need to add as  `strftime("%m-%d-%Y",dob) as dob_formatted` and that fixed it! Thank you!